# Generate hibernate static meta model from orm.xml with JAVA 11

Tags: hibernate, jaxb, java-11, jpamodelgen

I try to upgrade a project from java 8 to java 11. During the build process, we generate hibernate static meta model from orm.xml file.

When using a jdk11 for the maven build `mvn clean install`. StaticModel class are not generated and "target/generated-sources/annotations" is empty.
With a debug point in *org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.xml.JpaDescriptorParser#L153*. I manage to retrieve the real error message.

**Error message**

> Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.

Ok so its links to the removal of jaxb in Java 11.

I made a simple project to showcase my issue : https://github.com/epi-fr/hibernate-orm-xml-java11

I try several approach to import jaxb during the generation phase. But I didn't manage to generate the static model.

Base on [Mkyong article](https://mkyong.com/java/jaxbexception-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-module-path-or-classpath/) (point 6.3). I managed to go further, i think, but I get this strange error :

New exception message at *org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.xml.JpaDescriptorParser#L153*.

> ClassCastException: attempting to cast
> jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class to
> jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.  Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.

I push my change on the demo project on the branch "try_import_jaxb2.3".

Any idea to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's no way to fix this unfixed issue or by forking the latest hibernate 5.x and patch it.

Found this [issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12991) in Hibernate which explains a lot about the issue you are into (the important part is the 2nd newest comment by Hack Kampbjørn).

Trying to override jaxb-runtime / jaxb-api doesn't solve the problem neither.

**EDIT**

Updating to Hibernate 6 fails too.

Created issue in Hibernate : https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17579

PR created : https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/7646 (fix version would be 6.4.2.Final). Tested against https://github.com/laurentschoelens/hibernate-orm-xml-java11 OK

**EDIT 2**

PR merged in Hibernate. This will be available in v6.4.5 and v6.5.0
This should not make it's way to v5.6 but it's finally fixed

Comment: Thanks for pointing this issue. Not very encouraging... Even upgrade to hibernate 6 / orm 3 doesn't seems to work for now.

Comment: Same thing for me, always got the classpath issue. I've not recovered yet my Hibernate account but when done, I'll try putting down a note that this still doesn't work at all with jdk9+, even with the latest release

Comment: @EmericPinon : created issue in Hibernate https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17579

Comment: @EmericPinon : this will be fixed in Hibernate v6.5.0